# How does Freebase use the data in Yago2?

Tags: freebase

I read that Freebase uses Yago. How exactly does it use the data in Yago? Is it assured that all the data that is in Yago is represented by Freebase in its own way?

Comment: Stating where you read it would be useful context.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to YAGO+F project Tom. I read this statement here - http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/yago-naga/yago/applications.html which says "YAGO technology has been exported to Freebase." I am wondering if it is just the Ontology construction idea or any data present in Yago2 as well. Thanks!

Comment: I don't really know what they meant by that.  They may have "exported," but I never saw any evidence that it was "imported" on the Freebase end.  Lists like that are also intended to show the research is widely used and has had an impact, so they can be overstated, intentionally or not.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a coding question in there?

The YAGO team has done work to align YAGO & Freebase in their [YAGO+F Project](http://iqp.l3s.uni-hannover.de/yagof.html), but that's published as a separate dataset which is not included in Freebase.